# Delphi TclDownLoader problems on a service project

Tags: delphi

I am using Delphi Rio to develop a service to make an update program.
I have created a TComponent to encapsulated all the work.
The component work as expected used in a normal VCL project, but is not working as expected when used in a service project.

here is the code:

```
function TTaurineUpgrade.DownloadFile(serverURL, localFile: String): Boolean;
var workConnection : TclDownLoader;
    strError       : String;
    timeOut        : Integer;
    tmpInteger     : Int64;
begin
  Result   := False;
  strError := '';
  if not IsURLExist(serverURL, tmpInteger) then begin
    raise Exception.Create(Format('Fisierul %S nu exista pe server!', [serverURL]));
  end;
  try
    try
      WriteFeedback(EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, eInformation, 'Conectare server Elite Soft Media pentru download file...', '', True);
      WriteNotifyEventFeedback(_InfoVisibleDownloadInfo);
      workConnection                       := TclDownLoader.Create(Application);
      if Assigned(fProgressBar) then begin
        fProgressBar.InternetControl       := workConnection;
      end;
      workConnection.OnStatusChanged       := DownLoaderMainStatusChanged;
      workConnection.OnError               := DownLoaderMainError;
      workConnection.URL                   := serverURL;
      workConnection.LocalFolder           := writingPathFiles;
      workConnection.LocalFile             := localFile;

      workConnection.Start(True);
      fStatusTransfer := psUnknown;

      IsAbortDownload := False;
      while (fStatusTransfer <> psSuccess) do begin
        WriteFeedback(EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, eInformation, Format('fStatusTransfer = %S', [GetProcessStatusAsString(fStatusTransfer)]), '', False);
        if IsAbortDownload then begin
          WriteFeedback(EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE, eWarning, 'IsAbortDownload=True, Break', '', True);
          Break;
        end;
        Sleep(1000);
        ApplicationProcessMessages;
      end;
      workConnection.CloseConnection;
      WriteFeedback(EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, eInformation, 'Inchidere conexiune server Elite Soft Media...', '', True);
      if IsAbortDownload then begin
        WriteFeedback(EVENTLOG_WARNING_TYPE, eWarning, 'IsAbortDownload=True, Abort', '', True);
        Abort;
      end;
      Result := True;
    except
      on e : Exception do begin
        strError := e.Message;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    if Assigned(workConnection) then begin
      FreeAndNil(workConnection);
    end;
    WriteNotifyEventFeedback(_InfoNotVisibleDownloadInfo);
  end;
  Sleep(500);
  ApplicationProcessMessages;
  if strError <> '' then begin
    raise Exception.Create(strError);
  end;
end;


procedure TTaurineUpgrade.DownLoaderMainStatusChanged(Sender: TObject; Status: TclProcessStatus);
begin
  case Status of
    psErrors : WriteFeedback(EVENTLOG_ERROR_TYPE, eError, 'Eroare in functia DownLoaderMainStatusChanged', '', True);

  end;
  fStatusTransfer := Status;
end;

procedure TTaurineUpgrade.DownLoaderMainError(Sender: TObject; const Error: String; ErrorCode: Integer);
begin
  raise Exception.Create((Sender as TclDownLoader).Errors.Text);
end;
```

when using the component in service it stay forever in the while loop. (in the most of the cases) sometime is working (rarely)

anyone have a hint?

Comment: hard to say? My guess is that your tcldownloader component relies on a message pump which you don't have in your service thread. Please show the part of the service code also...

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `ApplicationProcessMessages` but instead [ServiceThread.ProcessRequests](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.SvcMgr.TServiceThread.ProcessRequests) when dealing with Service Applications

Comment: I am not using it. my function ApplicationProcessMessages (check it does not have dot), is making use of one constant to do or not do the Application.ProcessMessages;

Comment: procedure TTaurineUpgrade.ApplicationProcessMessages;
    begin
      if typeOFApplication = _ApplicationDesktop then begin
        Application.ProcessMessages;
      end;
    end;

Comment: First of all you should have provided the code of this procedure with provided code in your question. Second of all your `TTaurineUpgrade.ApplicationProcessMessages` procedure doesn't do anything when being used in service application which may actually be the problem. For instance if your downloading relies on events those events might never be processed because code stays in your while loop and doesn't give service a chance to process its message queue. That is why `ServiceThread.ProcessRequests` exists so that you can stil handle some messages during long process if needed

Comment: understood. In the while loop of the component, if there is a service project to "ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(False);" I will try it. tks.

Comment: don't do that! do not implement serviceexecute (it will call ProcessRequests for you) instead move the download code to a thread and spin up the thread at service start and end the thread at service stop.